# Как заставить telegram-бота отвечать на команды в Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Не выходило заставить  бота отвечать на команду, конкретно для начала хотел запрограммировать его на ответ команде `/start` использовал такую конструкцию:

```
@bot.message_handler (command=['start'])
def handler_start (message):
bot.send_message (message.from_user.id, 'Добрый день я бот...')
bot.polling (none stop=True)
```

Вот, при запуске кода выскакивает просто дохрена ошибок синтаксиса и т.д. Kак исправить?

Python 3.6.6, использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Ошибка в том что вы неправильно назвали параметр в декоратере,, нужно `commands=[]` а не `command=[]` и не `none stop` а `none_stop`

Comment: У меня иногда впн перестает нормально работать и выдает ошибку хотя код в порядке

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам поможет данный вариант:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def answer_to_command(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добрый день я бот...')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler (commands=['start'])
def handler_start(message):
        bot.send_message (message.chat.id, 'Добрый день я бот...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое я попробую !

Comment: Что-то не выходит, всё равно выдаёт эту ошибку, может у меня какая-то фигня с телебот ?

Comment: Вроде те ошибки исчезли но после он начал выдавать ошибку синтаксиса: File "D:/python/__main__.py", line 15 
 if __name__ == '__main__': 
 ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax